# Deployment problem in jboss 6

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x

I have built an application that works fine in the jboss 4.2 version but when i deploy it in jboss 6 version i am getting this error.

```
    22:05:36,201 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Parse: name=vfs:///C:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/rohan.war state=PreParse mode=Manual requiredState=Parse: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for vfs:///C:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/rohan.war
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:383) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:343) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:315) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.deploy(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:255) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.deploy(HDScanner.java:240) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.complete(HDScanner.java:192) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(TwoPCActionWrapper.java:57) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:135) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:146) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:90) [:0.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: vfs:///C:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/rohan.war/WEB-INF/lib/bsf-2.3.0.jar/META-INF/taglib.tld@4,63
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:224) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:178) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:257) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.xb.util.JBossXBHelper.parse(JBossXBHelper.java:231) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:137) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployment.TldParsingDeployer.parse(TldParsingDeployer.java:64) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployment.TldParsingDeployer.parse(TldParsingDeployer.java:38) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.SchemaResolverDeployer.parse(SchemaResolverDeployer.java:121) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.handleMultipleFiles(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:446) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.spi.deployer.AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.parse(AbstractVFSParsingDeployer.java:319) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.createMetaData(AbstractParsingDeployerWithOutput.java:376) [:2.2.0.GA]
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglib_1_1.dtd
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1311) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl.jar:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:209) [jbossxb.jar:2.0.3.GA]
    ... 51 more

22:05:36,211 WARN  [org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner] Scan failed: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

*** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

vfs:///C:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/rohan.war -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for vfs:///C:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/rohan.war


DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///C:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/rohan.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglib_1_1.dtd

    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1370) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1316) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:968) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:82) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.checkComplete(ProfileControllerContext.java:138) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.deploy(HDScanner.java:246) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.complete(HDScanner.java:192) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(TwoPCActionWrapper.java:57) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:135) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:146) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:90) [:0.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_18-ea]
```

Comment: JBoss 6 is massively different from JBoss 4. It is **not** 100% backwards compatible. JBoss 6 is a **Java EE 6** platform. I seriously doubt that  your app is a Java EE 6 app if it was running on JBoss 4.

Comment: @Mat Ball - You are right, but the problem at least seems to be different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is clear from the error that `http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglib_1_1.dtd` cannot be found. The correct name is `http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd`. The culprit configuration file is the following tag library descriptor: `C:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/rohan.war/WEB-INF/lib/bsf-2.3.0.jar/META-INF/taglib.tld`

Comment: While you may be right about this particular deployment error (I can't say either way because I didn't bother to look at the stack trace) - I'm sure there will be a large number of other issues as well. I'd imagine the entire app needs to be migrated from J2EE to JEE 6...

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently doing a migration like yours, for problems like `bsf-2.3.0.jar/META-INF/taglib.tld@4,63` I've open my tag lib jars, in your case `bsf-2.3.0.jar` and edit the specified file `META-INF/taglib.tld` in the line `4` column `63` and correct the name like Petar Minchev sugested.

Answer (score 0):

This exception mostly after validating application and then deploying that to J boss server but after adding deployment try to clean build your project and try again to start or debug server it may fix problem and in other way close IDE and open it again build app and start server I mostly faces that problem thanks